# Are Linux Security Modules runtime-loadable?

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, linux-security-module

Is it possible to compile Linux Security Modules as optional modules (.ko) and load them at runtime (or boottime)?

The modules in the Linux source tree seem to need to be compiled into the kernel (and can be selected via kernel boot params).

Just wondering if a loadable LSM is possible in a supported fashion?

Comment: If they have a `tristate` in their respective *Kconfig* options.

Comment: From playing around it seems that security_add_hooks() is in a NX-protected page at runtime so calling it from a loadable module doesn't seem possible (even after kallsyms is used to resolve it) - at least on my Arch kernel :( Alas